# Intermittent Problems loading type

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, pageload

I have a SharePoint site that I have added a few extra pages to in order to handle some custom AJAX requests.

Every now and then, about once a week, I get a call saying it's not working.  When I look into it, the error I'm receiving is:

```
Could not load type 'My_Controls.Control_Name' .
```

Where My_Controls.Control_Name is the name of the page.  An IIS restart solves the issue and gets it running again, but this is obviously of great concern to the client.

I have tried everything I could think of.  In the past when I encountered this, setting compilation batch="false" usually did the trick, but this time it isn't resolving the problem.

Obviously this is a pain to troubleshoot because there isn't a way to reproduce the bug (it just pops up from time to time) and a simple IIS restart solves it.

Does anyone know what may be causing this or ideas to try and fix it?

Thanks

Comment: what's in the various logs?  are you using the Ajax Control Toolkit, or something else?  where are the pages added to (application or site?)  is there an associated assembly?  if so is it GAC'd or in the bin dir?

Comment: It's just a boring old ASPX page that handles AJAX requests.  I doesn't use the AJAX tool kits.  The files are uploaded to the site, and the associated assembly is in the BIN directory.

Comment: Is the question still relevant?